# Access remote Windows server FILES from Linux Apache Webserver via Browser Hyperlink

Tags: php, html, apache

I have installed an apache webserver on Linux Debian and created an intranet on it. The intranet basically shows tables with entries from sql queries via php and mysql.
In one of these tables I would like to add a hyperlink that leads to/opens files and folders on a remote windows server.
I can access these files on the windows server from my linux webserver via cifs protocol.

How do I tell apache and/or linux where they need to go when a user clicks on a hyperlink in my intranet?
The path for the windows server is: **\10.0.10.100\data\moredata\file.xls**
I can access the windows server folders on my linux webserver via the following path: **/media/data/moredata/file.xls**
However, if I place this path inside html tag like this: 
`<a href="/media/data/moredata/file.xls">open my file please</a>` , it won't work.
If I try it like this: `<a href="/10.0.10.100/data/moredata/file.xls">open my file please</a>` , it also won't work.

I believe that I need to insert the path inside apache.conf ? Is this correct? And if so, how is it done exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Alias for that. Like 10.0.10.100/media can be pointing to your root /media folder. You can do it in your config file. Hope this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630774/web-root-alias-directory) can help.